# How do I get a field from a sub-relation in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Objective:**

Include `category_name` field in `$posts` attributes. The corresponding FK - `category_id` is currently included in my return.

**Controller returns all `Posts` with their `PostChild`s**

`return $posts = Post::with('postchildren')->get();`

**Post Model hasMany PostChild**

```
public function postchildren() {
    $this->hasMany('App\PostChild')
}
```

**PostChild Model hasOne Category**

(This table has a `category_id` field which is a FK for `id` in the `Category` model.)

```
 public function category() {
    $this->hasOne('App\Category');
 }
```

**Category Model**

This table has a `category_name` field

Comment: Have you setup the relationship on the PostChild model to the Category model? e.g. public function category() etc....

Comment: @Owen I have this in `PostChild`:

 `public function category()
    {
        $this->hasOne('category');
    }`

Comment: Can you share the result of `dd(Post::with(['postchildren', 'postchildren.category'])->get()->toJson());`

Comment: @Owen I get the following error: `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`

Comment: Have you tried https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get all the categories associated with the children via the HasManyThrough relationship e.g.

```
class Post
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(PostChild::class, Category::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can access the categories directly on the post object e.g.

```
$categories = Post::first()->categories;
```

or if you're wanting an array of them something like

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->get();
```

If you always want the `categories` loaded on the Post class you can define

```
class Post
{
    protected $with = ['categories'];
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting `categories` in my collection, but they aren't accessible within the `PostChild` array. Any idea how to get that?

Comment: if your PostChild model already has the relationship, they can just be accessed via the category method, e.g. `$postChild->category->category_name`